# Penetration test on JSON Api

Tags: json, penetration-testing

On my site a penetration test was performed. The following JSON was sent to the site:

```
{
    "name" : "Test',
}
```

This delivers the following error (with HTTP status code 400):

```
{
    "name": [
        "Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: \". Path 'name', line 3, position 1.",
        "Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path 'name', line 3, position 1."
    ]
}
```

The penetration tester says I should hide this error, because it could give a hint on vulnerabilities of my system.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this cannot be very straight forward until we look into your code and whether you have taken care of all security considerations. But on a general note, Improper Error Handling can reveal implementation details that should never be revealed. Such details can provide hackers important clues on potential flaws in the site.

Refer this URL for more details https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Improper_Error_Handling

For example, if I am a hacker then I will try and gather more information about your Deserialization logic and try to break it as you have clearly revealed to me. Deserialization is one of the new OWASP Top 10 Security Issue added 2017. You can please refer the below link for more details

https://www.owasp.org/images/d/d7/Marshaller_Deserialization_Attacks.pdf.pdf